# DIV height changes after inserting new HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have setup a video header in my homepage. I have setup javascript to remove the DIV (id=remove) with the video (after it ends running) and replace it with an image and 2 buttons.

What happens is that the next DIV below the Video/Image DIV (id=videoheader) is pushed down as the DIV increases in height.

I think there is something wrong with the css that positions the 2 buttons, because running it without inserting the 2 buttons nothing happens and all stays in place as expected.

I have tried to position the button relative and absolute without result. I have tried to adjust margins to position the next div that it does not move.

thanks for the help, Erwin

```
<div id="videoheader">
    <div id="show" class="page-video-containter">
        <div id="remove">
            <video id="myVideo" playsinline="" autoplay="" 
                muted="" class="page-media">
                <source src="testvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
            </video>
        </div>                   
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
        function myHandler(e) {
            var el = document.getElementById ("remove");
            el.remove();

            document.getElementById("show").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 
                '<img class="page-media" src="SL_STILLS_10.png"> <div 
                class="women"> <input type="button" class="button" 
                onclick="location.href=\'#\';" value="Women shop here" /> </div> 
                <br> <div class="men"> <input type="button" class="button" 
                onclick="location.href=\'#\';" value="Men shop here" /> </div>');
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
.page-video-container { 
    position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; 
}
.page-media { 
    position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; 
    left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background-size: cover; z-index: -1; 
    margin: 0; 
}
#videoheader {
    position: relative; margin: 0%; 
}
.videotext { 
    color: white; margin: 0px; padding: 20px; position: 
    absolute; top: 2%; font-size: 2vw; 
}
#videoheader .women .button {
    margin-top: -1%; position: absolute; 
    top: 5%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
#videoheader .men .button {
    margin-top: -1%; position: absolute; top: 
    10%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

Comment: On a test page, add both divs, make both divs visible and set them up to be the exact same height. Then you just have to hide one of the divs. In your js, when the video ends, hide the video-div, and show the other div. I think it's a bit over-complicated right now. And we can't figure it out without a working sample complete with video and images, etc.

Comment: I have set it up live on the actual home: www.stauntonlegend.com